# обработчик ссылки

Tags: php

Пишу сайт для записи на мероприятие. То есть, человек пишет данные и это записывается в базу, и человеку вдаётся страница с билетом для пропуска чтобы юзер смог его распечатать. Так вот, сделал дизайн, регистрацию, пополнение баланса, авторизацию, а вот главная часть осталось - то есть, выше описанное и админка. Их не могу сделать, не знаю с чего начать. Типа, админ в админке создает мероприятие, для этого мероприятия создает этаж, а в этаже создает комнату с указанием числа мест. Прошу помощи магистров!

1. Админ в своей админке создает мероприятие.
2. Админ для каждого мероприятия создает этажи, а в этажах комнаты с их вместимостью.
3. А юзер приходить кликает на мероприятие перед ним открывается форма.
4. Юзер вбивает свои данные (имя, фамилию, и т.д) и нажимает на кнопку "Участвовать на мероприятии"
5. После нажатия на кнопку "Участвовать на мероприятии". PHP скрипт сам автоматически записывает этого юзера, например, в 2-ой этаж 3-ю комнату место номер 7.
6. После этого данные, которые он написал, записывается в базу.
7. И перекидывает юзера на страницу с введенными юзером данными, чтобы он мог распечатать это как билет (пропуск).
8. И эта страница с его данными записывается на страницу, типа `example.com/BJJM=515JH`, чтобы юзер в любое время смог распечатать свой билет(пропуск) по ссылке `example.com/BJJM=515JH`.

Вот этим кодом ввожу все мероприятия:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th><h2>Event</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Event data</h2></th>
        <th><h2>Empty place</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $Evn = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `events`");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Evn)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['event_name'] .'</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['event_data'] .'</td>';
            echo '<td>empty</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

И вот мне надо сделать чтобы при нажатии на `echo '<td>'. $row['event_name'] .'</td>';` открывалась форма для записи на мероприятие (их несколько). Не делать же для каждого мероприятия страницу с формой записи. Типа, должно быть так:

```
   echo '<td><a href="'">'. $row['event_name'] .'</a></td>';
```

Comment: вам нужно на уровне конфигов веб-сервера переписать ссылки. для апача это обычно делается в .htaccess правилами mod_rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо сделать одну общую форму для записи на мероприятие.

Внутри формы в `<input type="hidden" name="event_name" value="" />` передавать ваш `event_name`.

Форму можно сразу разместить на странице с табличкой, а показывать с помощью java-script, заполняя скрытое поле `event_name`.

Также очень советую запретить показывать ссылки `example.com/BJJM=515JH` без авторизации во избежание злоупотреблений.